# Getting text from Selenium + Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, element, whatsapp

[image]

Cannot get the "You can't join this group because it is full." as a text. Please help me.
Please also tell me the code using Beautiful Soup.

Comment: share your code

Comment: You will have to rework this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the XPath

```
//div[contains(@class,'_31LzD')]/div[text()='You can't join this group because it is full']
//div[contains(@class,'_3QNwO')]//precding::div[text()='You can't join this group because it is full']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the class name doesn't change, you can use:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'_31LzD')]/div")
```

If the class does change, you could always work down from a 'fixed' element like `.copyable-area`:

```
browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'copyable-area')]/div/div/div/div/div")
```

If you know the text itself won't change, you can query it based on the text content:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'You can't join this group because it is full')]")
```